# Am I doing something wrong on my Foursquare venue search API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, jsonp, foursquare

I signed up for a new account, registered for an Oauth token from the foursquare website.

Then I hit this in my browser:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&callback=location&oauth_token=my_token_here
```

But that doesn't work!

It says:

```
location({"meta":{"code":401,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"OAuth token not found or has been revoked."},"response":{}});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved.

You have to provide your client secret and client id.

Comment: If I need to use it from the browser (i.e. JavaScript) then the "Client Secret" won't be "secret" anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Example Call: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=37.835819,-87.931824&client_secret=XXX&client_id=YYYY